# Push Notifications not received by Android device if it is kept idle for long

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am able to send remote notifications using GCM to Android devices successfully.However on some devices if the device is kept idle for very long time then the notification is not received.I am facing the problem on xiaomi redmi note 4 device and it works fine on other android devices.I have also tried using FCM,but the problem is the same.I have followed the tutorial from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/)
to implement push notification using FCM and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-gcm/) to implement remote notification using GCM.Is there any setting that I need to enable?Is the issue device specific?

Comment: the issue is not the push service, but Xiaomi's memory management application. Just add your application to the whitelist of the memory management app they have. https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/5fhs22/ram_optimization_on_miui_8/

Answer (score 1):

Xiaomi devices automatically stop background services. For run your service long time into your xiaomi device then you need to give permission of autorun in device. If you allow your app for autorun then service can run long time into your device.

Below is code snippet for ask auto run permission in xiaomi device.

```
if (TextUtils.equals(Build.MANUFACTURER, "Xiaomi"){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: If you get your solution then please accept this answer, So other can get it easily.

Comment: That is not working for me.The same problem occurs on Asus_Z00UD also.

Comment: Same Problem Occurs in Lenovo Tab 3